# How to run function after event is run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I am a beginner with all coding. Here is my general goal. I am running something relatively simple where I have 8 superheroes on the screen. I would like the user to eliminate the 4 DC superheroes from the screen and after all 4 of them are eliminated from the screen I want the system to alert the user that they have won the game. They don't have to do it in any order so I ran the superHero function each time a DC character was clicked to check if all four DC superheroes had been eliminated yet. Somebody please help me. I feel like it is something very simple I am messing up on. Thanks a ton in advance.

```
/*This is my jquery that shows all 8 of my superheroes*/
$('#heroes').show();    
var flashHidden = !$('#greenlantern').is(':visible');
var greenHidden = !$('#greenlantern').is(':visible');
var batmanHidden = !$('#batman').is(':visible');
var supermanHidden = !$('#superman').is(':visible');     
function superHero() {
    if(flashHidden && batmanHidden && supermanHidden && greenHidden) {
        alert ("Congratulations!!! You have won the game!! Please proceed forward and fill out a quick survey for the developers");
    }
}    
$('#flash').click(function(){
    $('#flash').hide('slow',function(){
        superHero();
    });
});    
$('#greenlantern').click(function(){
    $('#greenlantern').hide('slow',function(){
        superHero();
    });
});   
$('#batman').click(function(){
    $('#batman').hide('slow',function(){
        superHero();
    });
});
$('#superman').click(function(){
    $('#superman').hide('slow',function(){
        superHero();
    });
});
});
```

Right now the current thing that is happening is I will eliminate all of the correct superheroes and it will not alert me that the user has won. I've tried a lot of different things and the only other result I've gotten is to have the system alert the user every time they click on a superhero that they've won which is also incorrect.

***EDIT***

This has been solved by changing the scope of the variables to inside the function.

Comment: You should add your solution as a answer rather than an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your variables i.e. flashHidden in your function. Currently you are setting then at the start.

```
function superHero() {
    var flashHidden = !$('#flash').is(':visible');
    var greenHidden = !$('#greenlantern').is(':visible');
    var batmanHidden = !$('#batman').is(':visible');
    var supermanHidden = !$('#superman').is(':visible'); 
    if(flashHidden && batmanHidden && supermanHidden && greenHidden) {
        alert ("Congratulations!!! You have won the game!! Please proceed forward and fill out a quick survey for the developers");
    }
}
```

Additionally your click handler can be condensed into

```
$('#flash, #greenlantern, #batman, #superman').click(function(){
    $(this).hide('slow',function(){
        superHero();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually like Satpal's way of doing it better.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you for the shorthand, I didn't know that you could do that. Putting the variables in the scope of the function was the magic behind it. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MarcusSparks4, shorthand is called [multiple selectors.](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting...

```
var flashHidden = !$('#greenlantern').is(':visible');
```

...to start with.  But you're not updating that variable later on when it gets hidden.  So according to your check of:

```
if(flashHidden && batmanHidden && supermanHidden && greenHidden) {
```

...Flash is still visible.  Even though, yes, on the page he's gone.

Try adding this:

```
$('#flash').click(function(){
    $('#flash').hide('slow',function(){
        flashHidden=true;
        superHero();
    });
});
```